# vector and position and acceleration

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, vectors

I really need your help with two problems.

1. Consider a moving object that can be described by the position function
   r(t) = [(8.00m/s )t-[( 4.50m/s^3 )t^3 ]î +(− 2.00 )t^2+10.0m]ĵ In unit­vector notation, determine the position, velocity, and acceleration vectors of the object at time t = 4.00s. What is the speed (magnitude of the velocity vector) of the object at t = 4.00s?
2. A person is throwing a ball at a target 19.0m away and 0.500m above the ground. If
   the ball is released horizontally at a height of 2.00m, at what speed must the ball be
   released in order to hit the target? (This problem is an approximation of a fastball
   pitcher throwing a baseball into the catcher’s mitt sitting just behind home plate.

any help will be appreciated thanks

Comment: i don't know where to start on the first one, but the second one i tried to solve it geometrically but i got stuck. is there like a kinematic equation that could help

Comment: Please note that Physics.StackExchange is *not* a homework help site. Please [see this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.So you have a position vector given by $$\vec{r}=\left(8t-4.5t^3\right)\hat{i}+\left(10-2t^2\right)\hat{j}$$ If you use the definition of velocity as $$\vec{v}=\frac{d\vec{r}}{dt}$$
then we differentiate each component of the vector to get the velocity vector.
$$\vec{v}=\left(8-13.5t^2\right)\hat{i}+\left(-4t^2\right)\hat{j}$$
Acceleration $\vec{a}$ is defined as $$\vec{a}=\frac{d\vec{v}}{dt}=\frac{d^2\vec{r}}{dt^2}$$
$$\vec{a}=\left(-27t\right)\hat{i}+\left(-8t\right)\hat{j}$$

So these expressions give you the instantaneous velocity and acceleration as a function of time, so putting in $t=4$ will give you the values you need. To get the value of the speed you need to calculate $$|\vec{v}|=\sqrt{\vec{v}\cdot\vec{v}}$$.

2. This part is about using the kinematic equations of constant acceleration in the vertical and horizontal directions and simultaneously solving for the velocity.

Firstly you need to calculate how long it takes the ball to fall through $1.5$m (the difference in starting height and end height). So using one of the eqns of constant acceleration $d_{vert}=ut+\frac{1}{2}gt^2$ with $u=0$ as the ball starts from rest in the vertical plane (thrown horizontally) and $g$ is acceleration due to gravity. So the time it takes is then given by $$t=\sqrt{\frac{2d_{vert}}{g}}$$.

Since we have this time the horizontal component is easy, the velocity $v$ is just given by $$v=\frac{d_{horz}}{t}$$ as the times must be the same for the ball to arrive in the catcher's hand. $d_{horz}=19$m

Putting it all together
$$v=\frac{d_{horz}}{\sqrt{\frac{2d_{vert}}{g}}}$$

Leave a comment if there is a mistake or something that is confusing (it's pretty late where I am)

Comment: OMG man you saved my bacon.